# What is the reason that the code is not running?

Tags: java, eclipse, hashmap

I'm a beginner and I have tried a few different ways from the stuff that I have learned from other people's questions, but still, I can't get my code running.

```
 import java.util.HashMap;
 import java.util.Scanner;
 import java.util.Set;
 import java.util.HashSet;
 import java.util.Map;


public class Utilities {

private HashMap<String,Integer> myMap;

public Utilities() {
    myMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
}

public void populateHashMap() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(input.hasNext()) {
        String next = input.next();
        Integer count = myMap.get(next);
        if(myMap != null) {
            myMap.put(next, count + 1);
        }else {
            myMap.put(next, 1);
        }
    }
    input.close();
}

public void displayCollection() {
    populateHashMap();
    Set<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> enteries = myMap.entrySet();
    for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> entery : enteries) {
        System.out.print("Key: " + entery.getKey());
        System.out.print(", Value" + entery.getValue());
    }
}

 public static void main(String[] args) {
 Utilities demo = new Utilities();
 demo.populateHashMap();
 demo.displayCollection();

 }
}
```

I'm supposed to create the following methods:

- A Method populateHashMap(), the method will use the scanner and get a text piece from the user. Each word will be used as a key, the integer will be the number of times the word appears in the text.
- A Method displayCollection(), the method will display each key and the number of times it appeared in the given text.

If someone can please tell me why I can't get this to code running, I would appreciate it.

Comment: What does "I can't get this to code running" mean? Does it compile? If not, what is the error? If it does, what happens when you run it? Is there an error? If so, what is it?

Comment: I can see that if it does run, you'll get an `IllegalStateException`, because you run `populateHashMap` twice (once directly, once from inside `displayCollection`), and you close `System.in` - the second time this will fail.

Comment: @AndyTurner It compiles, but no command line will appear to type in.

Comment: "but no command line will appear to type in" How are you running it?

Comment: @AndyTurner Should I just remove the input.close() and populateHashMap() from the displayCollection() method?

Comment: @AndyTurner I just click on the green button that does the running function in Eclipse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many problems in your code:

1. You should never close `Scanner` for `System.in`; otherwise, `System.in` will also be closed and there is no way to open it again. It means that if you try to scan anything again from `System.in`, your program will fail.
2. In the following code, you have performed an operation on `myMap` and then you have checked if it is `null` which will not never be reached if `myMap` is `null`.

```
Integer count = myMap.get(next);
if (myMap != null) {
    //...
}
```

**Side notes:**

3. You should always display some message before any input so that the user can know what is the expected input.
4. You can simplify `populateHashMap` as follows:

```
public void populateHashMap() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter the words: ");
    String line = input.nextLine();
    for (String next : line.split("\\s+")) {
        myMap.put(next, myMap.getOrDefault(next, 0) + 1);
    }
}
```

5. There is no reason why you should call `populateHashMap()` from `displayCollection()`.
6. The method, `displayCollection()` can also be simplified as follows:

```
public void displayCollection() {
    for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Key: " + entry.getKey() + ", Value: " + entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

Given below is the code incorporating all these comments:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Utilities {

    private HashMap<String, Integer> myMap;

    public Utilities() {
        myMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    }

    public void populateHashMap() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the words separated by space: ");
        String line = input.nextLine();
        for (String next : line.split("\\s+")) {
            myMap.put(next, myMap.getOrDefault(next, 0) + 1);
        }
    }

    public void displayCollection() {
        for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : myMap.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("Key: " + entry.getKey() + ", Value: " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Utilities demo = new Utilities();
        demo.populateHashMap();
        demo.displayCollection();
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter the words separated by space: hello hi bye hello bye
Key: hi, Value: 1
Key: hello, Value: 2
Key: bye, Value: 2
```

Comment: That helped me a lot understanding the logic of my code. Thank you.